# Doesn't rvalue reference mix together type and category?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, value-categories

This post reflects my current level of understanding of a value category.

Value category is a property of an expression.
Type is a propetry of a variable.

Let's say we have the following declaration:

```
int x;
```

What is x? It is a variable and it is an expression.

Writing a new syntax like this:

```
int&& ref
```

instead of

```
int& ref
```

makes people think that we've done something related to types, but actually we've done something related to expressions, not types. (We've specified what expressions can be bound to these variables.)

Probably distinguishing between "temporaries" and "non-temporaries" could be done another way, maybe something like this:

```
void func(int&); // for "non-temporaries"
void func((int&)); // for "temporaries
```

or some other way, but not fiddling with types.

So my question is:
Is it necessary to encode information about an expression category into a syntax for types? What were the reasons for this design decision?

Comment: "We've specified what expressions can be bound to these variables." is what the type of a reference is all about.  You won't claim that `int& r1;` and `float& r2;` differ in value category will you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rvalue references are a distinct type from lvalue references so that they can encode something: the user's specific intent when they created that reference. If you make an rvalue reference, you specifically intend that the object it references can be moved from. That is a separate intent from using an lvalue reference.

That specific intent is not detectable from just the use of the name; the value category of an rvalue reference variable is lvalue. But that intent is detectable from the *type*. And the type matters.

We want to be able to overload functions on this declared intent, to have one overload that can take an object which can be moved from and another that doesn't. This is the basis of the distinction between a copy constructor and a move constructor. C++ overloads functions based on types, so... we must specify this intent at the type level.

In your `func` example, if `int&` and `(int&)` are the same type, then by the rules of C++ as it currently exist, both of those `func` functions declare the *same function*. So you'd need to invent new rules that defines the concept of a "function signature" as being more than just the types involved. You'd have to mess with overload resolution to determine which function gets called. Etc.

Plus, `std::move` works (that is, the return value can bind to rvalue references) because the value category of a return value of rvalue reference type is defined to be an xvalue. And xvalues can bind to rvalue references. With your way, this `(&)` syntax would have to have similar properties. But it couldn't be based on the type, because by definition, it doesn't change the type. So in essence, you have to declare that reference types can have this extra, non-type, information sitting beside a type. This information cannot be queried by any normal interface, unlike type information for an expression which can be queried by `decltype`.

Or you can just create a new type and get most of that for free. You still need to investigate how overload resolution works for this new type, and you still have to define rvalue reference binding rules, but the concept of a function signature is unchanged, and you don't need this awkward extra channel of information that sits beside a type.

The use of a reference for this intent also allows for reference-collapsing rules, which are the basis of "perfect" forwarding: the ability to write a single (template) function that forwards expressions of any value category to a destination in a way that leaves intact whether the destination can copy/move from them.

Comment: OK, we have encoded the value category in a type. But it turns out that overload resolution considers not the type: we still have to apply std::move to a rvalue reference parameter (of a function). I still don't undestand something here...

Comment: @beginpluses: I don't understand what you don't understand. We need some way to connect the return value of `std::move` with the parameter, in such a way that overloads which express the intent to move from the object will be prioritized over those which don't. There has to be some way in a function signature to differentiate a reference you intend to move from from a reference you don't intend to move from. Since overloading is based on types, you need a new type to recognize that.

Comment: @beginpluses: "*But it turns out that overload resolution considers not the type*" Overload resolution considers two sets of things: the types and value categories of the arguments (the values you're passing), and the types of the parameters in the candidate functions. So yes, it is considering type information. Indeed, value categories consider type information too; a function call that returns a `T&&` is an xvalue, while a function call that returns a `T&` is an lvalue. So types are being considered in a lot of places.

Comment: I don't understand the following. struct X { std::vector<int> m_v; X(std::vector<int>& v); X(std::vector<int>&& v): m_v(std::move(v)) {} }; Why to apply std::move if the parameter v is of type std::vector<int>&&?

Comment: The compiler knows that v is of type std::vector<int>&& (and not of type std::vector<int>&). So why to apply std::move?

Comment: @beginpluses: Because movement is *destructive*, so you don't want a user to do it *by accident*. So the rules are set up so that you only implicitly move if the user asks for it or if it is clearly safe (such as functions that return a value, or if you create a temporary as an argument, or if you're returning a local object from a function, or etc). Also, `m_v(v)` has a meaning: copy. If you want it to mean move, you need to have some way to say that.

Comment: @beginpluses: Also, you're veering off-topic. Your question was about why C++ uses a type-based mechanism for move support rather than using syntax that is not part of the type. I answered that. Now you're asking about why you can't implicitly move from named rvalue references; that's a completely different topic, which has nothing to do with the specific way you spell these things out. That is, even in your hypothetical syntax, you would *still* need to use `move` there, because the reason for that `move` has nothing to do with how you spell the construct.

Comment: I asked here again because I think that the second question is very very close to the first one. We've agreed that value category is encoded in a type, right? std::vector ctor is overloaded for & and &&. The type of v is &&. m_v(v) must be MOVE, not COPY. But nevertheless things work in a different way.

Comment: @beginpluses: "*We've agreed that value category is encoded in a type, right?*" No, we haven't, because that's not true. *Something* is encoded in the type, but it is *not* the value category. What's encoded was whether the code that initialized the reference intended to allow it to be moved from or not. That's not the same thing as the value category.